# C# Web Socket /server/ reads data as weird string

Tags: javascript, c#, sockets, websocket

As title suggests, the handshaking is working perfectly fine, however, when I try to send or receive messages, it all gets messed up. I honestly can't figure out why.

This is what my console reads:

```
[16:45:13] Connecting to the database at "root@127.0.0.1"...
[16:45:15] Connected to the database after (39ms).

[16:45:15] Reading server settings through the database...
[16:45:15] Read the server settings, continuing on...

[16:45:15] Initializing the socket server to listen for *:42168

[16:45:24] Incoming client connection from 127.0.0.1:53715
[16:45:24] Received from 127.0.0.1:53715 - GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:42168
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://127.0.0.1
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Sec-WebSocket-Key: BMMlXULj++J931bLGn/SYg==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits


[16:45:24] Received from 127.0.0.1:53715 - ???ug>
```

The very last message should be "`9`" but it¨'s shown as "`???ug>`".

```
SocketClient.socket.send("9");
```

Here's how I read the messages:

```
    public static void Init(IAsyncResult response)
    {
        //reuse
        SocketManager.server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(packets.OnClientConnected.Init, SocketManager.server);

        //

        TcpClient client = SocketManager.server.EndAcceptTcpClient(response);

        int client_port = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port;

        users.Users.Clients.TryAdd(client_port, new users.UserFactory(
            client_port,
            ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString(),
            false));

        ConsoleHandler.debug("Incoming client connection from " + users.Users.Clients[client_port].ClientIP + ":" + client_port.ToString());

        while(client.Connected == true)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];

            try
            {
                int receive = client.Client.Receive(data);
                if (receive == 0) return;

                new OnMessageReceived(client, client_port, Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receive));
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        new OnClientDisconnect(client, client_port);
    }
```

So, why's the web socket server malfunctioning?

Comment: Are you sure it is not unicode? ie. `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` ? Or perhaps the chosen ascii code page is different between server/client?

Comment: Hmm, good spot. Let me check.

Comment: @Igor nope.. same output from the server.

Comment: `TcpClient` is for raw TCP/IP-connections. It doesn't speak the web socket protocol, so you're getting the framing bytes for that. Use `HttpListener` and `HttpListenerContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync`.